# Display empty in formula cell, even if the `null` or `nil` is specified in corresponding reference column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to display the difference between two dates. dates and times are specified in separate cells. so I am using the below formula. Problem is `E11` and `G11` column can be empty or null or nil.

For empty I am using the below formula and it is working correctly.

`=IF((E11+G11)=0,"",((E12+G12)-(E11+G11))*24)`

But same if I try for null or nil. formula cell showing `#VALUE`.

`=IF((E11+G11)=0,"",IF(E11="NULL","",((E12+G12)-(E11+G11))*24))`

I'm trying to display empty even if `E11` and `G11` column having null or nil.

Can anyone help me to find the solution??

Answer (score 2):

> (E11+G11)=0

The above will give you the `#VALUE` if one of them is `Text`. Use `OR` instead

Try this

`=IF(OR(E11="",G11=""),"",IF(AND(OR(E11="NULL",E11="Nil"),OR(G11="NULL",G11="Nil")),"",((E12+G12)-(E11+G11))*24))`

[image]

Comment: +1 but what about `nil`? the part I dont understand in the question

Comment: @mehow: I had already seen that and I was updating my post. Finally updated :)

Comment: what is `nil` anyway? I see this once in a while but never know is it just a *word* aka replacement for *null*? why do some people use `nil`. Cause in like Obj-C it's a data type, in C is pointer but in excel people seem to abuse the meaning

Comment: @mehow: no this "Null","Nil" is not to be confused with `vbNull`. They are just text in a cell

Comment: yea I realize they are just `Text` as you are comparing against text I am just asking generally why `nil`

Comment: @mehow Let me upload a screenshot

Comment: @SiddharthRout the formula which u given is working fine in my excel. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `SUM` since this function ignores text:

```
=IF(SUM(E11,G11)=0,"",SUM(E12,G12,-E11,-G11)*24)
```

You mentioned that E11 and G11 can be null, and I'm understanding it as being both are as such, because otherwise, you'd have to check E11 and G11 separately if they contain null/nil.

Some case/outcome, with E11 and G11 interchangeable (dates and times are numbers):

```
E11      G11       Result
Number   Number    Calculation
Number   Nil       Calculation with whatever numbers are available
Number   Null      Calculation with whatever numbers are available
Number   Blank     Calculation with whatever numbers are available
Nil      Nil       Returns blank
Nil      Null      Returns blank
Nil      Blank     Returns blank
Null     Null      Returns blank
Null     Blank     Returns blank
Blank    Blank     Returns blank
```

If you want to calculate only if both E11 and G11 are numbers, then I would use this:

```
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(E11),ISNUMBER(G11)), (E12+G12-E11-G11)*24, "")
```